# Is this not the $n$-th root test stated on Wikipedia?

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the following theorem (in Bak/Newman):

**2.8 Theorem**

> Suppose $\overline{\lim} \vert C_k \vert ^{1/k} = L$.
>
> 1. If $L = 0$, $\sum C_k z^k$ converges for all $z$.
> 2. If $L = \infty$, $\sum C_k z^k$ converges for $z = 0$ only.
> 3. If $0 < L < \infty$, set $R = 1/L$.
>    Then $\sum C_k z^k$ converges for $\vert z \vert < R$ and diverges for $\vert z \vert > R$ ($R$ is called the radius of convergence of the power series.)

I thought this was just the [n-th root test as on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test) but the statement is totally different.

In 1. where $L=0$ above according to Wikipedia the radius of convergence would be $0$ so that the series would only converge for $z=0$ but in 1. it is all $z$.

> Could someone explain to me how these two statements, theorem 2.8 and
> the root test, differ?

Comment: It can be shown that the radius of convergence is exactly $\frac{1}{L}$, which is why the results stated are backward from what you're thinking.

Comment: the theorem reduces to a comparison with the geometric series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty R^{-n} z^n = \frac{1}{1-z/R}$ converges for $|z| < R$, diverges otherwise

Comment: This is *Hadamard's formula* for the radius of convergence of a power series. It is indeed very to the $n$-th root test, except it is the limit superior which is considered.

Answer (score 2):

The radius of convergence $R$ of a power series  $\sum c_kz^k$ is related to the coefficients by
$$
1/R=\limsup |c_k|^{1/k}
$$
So if 
$$
1/R=\limsup |c_k|^{1/k}=0\Rightarrow R=\infty
$$
I think the reciprocal is the source of your confusion. This is Cauchy-Hadamard

Comment: But on Wikipedia they distinguish the cases $C<1, C>1$ and $C=1$ whereas in the theorem they distinguish $C=0, C=\infty$ and $0 < C < \infty$. No?

Answer (score 0):

It's basically the same. Note that usually (as in Wiki) the limit considered is 
$$\frac{1}{\limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{|C_n|}},$$
whereas in your case, denominator and numerator are reversed. That's why the convergences are also reversed.